# nginx reverse proxy sending links in http

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have an nginx reverse proxy running based on the working setup [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/145383/proxy-https-requests-to-a-http-backend-with-nginx). It is sending  the page to our backend (apache) correctly except the page comes back with all links in http (page itself is https). I know that the configuration change needs to be done on the backend (apache), I just don't know where.

Here is my original setup:

```
    server {
listen 80;
server_name example.com;

rewrite ^(.*) https://$server_name$1 permanent;
 }
    server {
listen 443;
server_name example.com;

root   /var/web/;

ssl                  on;
ssl_certificate /etc/apache2/ssl/server.crt;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/apache2/ssl/server.key;

# -----------------------------------------------------------------
# https://mozilla.github.io/server-side-tls/ssl-config-generator/
# generate with openssl dhparam -out dhparams.pem 2048
ssl_dhparam /etc/apache2/ssl/dhparam.pem;


ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
ssl_session_timeout 1d;
ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:50m;
ssl_session_tickets off;

# Diffie-Hellman parameter for DHE ciphersuites, recommended 2048 bits
#ssl_dhparam /etc/pki/nginx/dh2048.pem;

# intermediate configuration. tweak to your needs.
ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
ssl_ciphers 'ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256:kEDH+AESGCM:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA:AES256-SHA:AES:CAMELLIA:DES-CBC3-SHA:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!RC4:!MD5:!PSK:!aECDH:!EDH-DSS-DES-CBC3-SHA:!EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:!KRB5-DES-CBC3-SHA';

location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
}
```

}

Apache config

```
    <VirtualHost *:8080>
    ServerName localhost:8080
    ServerAlias 127.0.0.1:8080
    DocumentRoot /var/web/
    DirectoryIndex index.html index.xhtml
# - absorb the shared virtual host settings
    </VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Please add full details of the setup to this question.

Comment: I ended up adding the line        "add_header 'Content-Security-Policy' 'upgrade-insecure-requests';" to my location directive which seems to have fixed it. Is this the correct way to set this up?

Comment: No, you need to configure whichever software is generating those links to create proper links.

Comment: Ok, I'll look into that. Thanks for the help

Comment: Just to update, Tero's answer was correct. I updated the perl module creating the links to get it working.

Answer (score 0):

Use `return` instead of `rewrite`.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
```